# Excel VBA: replacing part of formula for selected cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this kind of formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OLD!$A:$B,**2**,0),0)
```

And I want to select certain number of cells right of the first one, and then to fill them with formula that changes only `col_index_num` (increments by 1 for each next cell to the right)

And I have no idea how to do it in VBA. I could make a Autohotkey script, but a lot of my colleagues need this too, and Excel macro would be nice :)

Sheet names and cell ranges may differ from need to need, but just `col_index_num` needs to be incremented.

Comment: A macro is definitely overkill here. Where you have the "2" in your vlookup formula above, change it to this: "COLUMN(B:B)". This reduces to 2. As you drag the formula to the right, it will become "COLUMN(C:C)" [which reduces to 3], and so on.

Comment: but vlookup needs the first collumn to use as refference.

Comment: Your question is how to increment col_index_num. I have shown you how to do that. Do you also want to know how to make VLOOKUP always pick up column A on the left, and a newly iterated column n on the right? If so, just do this: VLOOKUP($A2,$A:B,2,0). Here, the $ to the left of A means it will always look at column A to the left. The lack of $ to the left of B means that as you drag the formula to the right, B will increment by 1.

Comment: I think Grade 'Eh' means `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OLD!$A:B,COLUMN(B:B),0),0)`.

Comment: it works, thanx a lot. Had no idea that I could use collumn refference for that. I always used flat number.